Android Studio on Linux - source editor freezes, everything else OK
I am having strange problems with the source editor of Android Studio intermittently freezing when focus goes to another app window and then returns. Everything else works fine, such as menus, but any existing or newly-created source windows remain uneditable unless I restart Android Studio (or occasionally if I just toggle screen-split).
I can't identify or recreate an exact sequence of events to cause this, but it happens all the time and it's basically unusable.
I see lots of reports of AS freezing, but it seems that's usually the entire application and is related to memory use or computer performance.
Mine is a light-use case on a powerful laptop where I haven't even used the emulator or done any builds yet in the app, in a relatively small project. This is on Koala 2024.1.1, Ubuntu 24.04.1. I'm using window focus-mode "Focus on Hover" (aka "sloppy") to follow the mouse cursor.
Have others encountered this?

I'm afraid I've had to revert to developing on Windows, because the Linux implementation was so fragile. Makes me very sad. Linux subsystem on Windows helps a little. The Linux implementation of AS/IntelliJ could use a lot more love.
